# Equals method to compare two trees

Tags: java

I have been learning java recently. And I created two trees. I need to write code(equals method) to compare two trees and if they are the same, then output true or false.

My Code:

```
public class TreePrint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Tree<String> rootFolder = new Tree<>("RootFolder");

        Node<String> video = rootFolder.addChild("Video");
        Node<String> music = rootFolder.addChild("Music");
        Node<String> picture = rootFolder.addChild("Picture");

        video.addChild("Terminator");
        video.addChild("Die Hard");
        video.addChild("Rocky");
        music.addChild("Eminem");
        Node<String> picture01 = picture.addChild("Picasso");
        picture01.addChild("Do Vinci");
        Node<String> picture02 = picture01.addChild("Adil");
        picture02.addChild("Cartoon");
        picture02.addChild("Comics");

         Tree2<String> rootFolder1 = new Tree2<>("RootFolder1");

        Node<String> video1 = rootFolder1.addChild("Video");
        Node<String> music1 = rootFolder1.addChild("Music");
        Node<String> picture1 = rootFolder1.addChild("Picture");

        video1.addChild("Terminator");
        video1.addChild("Die Hard");
        video1.addChild("Rocky");
        music1.addChild("Eminem");
        Node<String> picture001 = picture1.addChild("Picasso");
        picture001.addChild("Do Vinci");
        Node<String> picture002 = picture001.addChild("Adil");
        picture002.addChild("Cartoon");
        picture002.addChild("Comics");


        printTree(rootFolder);
        printTree(rootFolder1);


        boolean b1 = rootFolder.contains("P0");
        System.out.println(b1);
        boolean b2 = rootFolder1.contains("Eminem");
        System.out.println(b2);
    }

    private static <T> void printTree(Node<T> node) {
        printTree(node, 0);
    }

    private static <T> void printTree(Node<T> node, int level) {
        printNode(node, level);
        if (node.getChildren() != null) {
            for (Node childNode : node.getChildren()) {
                printTree(childNode, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private static <T> void printNode(Node<T> kid, int level) {

        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }

        System.out.println(kid.getData());
    }
}
```

---

first tree:

```
public class Tree<T> extends Node<T> {

    public Tree(T data) {

        super(data, null);
    }
    public boolean contains(T value) {
        return recurse(iterate(), value);
    }

    private boolean recurse(List<Node<T>> children, T value) {
        return children.stream()
                .anyMatch(item -> item.getData().equals(value) || item.iterate().size() > 0 && recurse(item.iterate(), value));
    }


}
```

---

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private final List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Node<T> parent;


    public Node(T data, Node<T> parent) {
        this.data = data;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void addChild(Node<T> node) {
        children.add(node);
    }


    public Node<T> addChild(T nodeData) {

        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>( nodeData, this ); 
        children.add( newNode );
        return newNode;
    }


    public List<Node<T>> iterate() {
        return children;
    }

    public void remove(Node<T> node) {
        children.remove(node);
    }

    public List<Node<T>> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
```

---

Second Tree:

```
public class Tree2<T> extends Node<T> {

    public Tree2(T data) {

        super(data, null);
    }
    public boolean contains(T value) {
        return recurse(iterate(), value);
    }

    private boolean recurse(List<Node<T>> children, T value) {
        return children.stream()
                .anyMatch(item -> item.getData().equals(value) || item.iterate().size() > 0 && recurse(item.iterate(), value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Two trees are identical when they have the same data. To identify if two trees are identical, you will need to traverse both trees simultaneously, and while traversing you need to compare data and children of the trees.

Comment: Can you please write the equals method

Comment: here is an algorithm and code for java: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-c-code-to-determine-if-two-trees-are-identical/

Comment: yes, click the link and see the java code. there is the method.

Comment: In the link is another tree, and there is no method equals

Comment: i only need method equals. Please help me write a code in my two trees

Comment: Why do you have two classes that do exactly the same ? What you need are two Tree objects, not two Tree classes.

Comment: Two class = two trees

Comment: @AdilAzrael your tree representation is over complicated. You don't need the `Tree` and `Tree2` classes (1 tree = 1 instance of `Node`, 2 trees = 2 instances of `Node`), you also don't need the `parent` attribute on the `Node` class.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following method to your Node class. Since your tree is also a node - you should be able to compare two trees. FYI, This is autogenerated by Eclipse.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Node other = (Node) obj;
    if (children == null) {
        if (other.children != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!children.equals(other.children))
        return false;
    if (data == null) {
        if (other.data != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!data.equals(other.data))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: And remember to add a `hashcode` method also complementing the `equals` method.

Comment: how to run it in the class treeprint

Comment: can help complete the exercise

Comment: a little bit left to run it in the treePrint class

Comment: how to run in class treeprint

Comment: `rootFolder.equals(rootFolder1)`?

Comment: How add Hashcoode. I don t added in class Node

Comment: I am finished. But 
I was told that it should be in the tree class and be recursive and this code does not work correctly ((

Comment: We have to raise a bug against Eclipse ;-). I do not think the issue is with the equals() method. May be it was invoked wrongly...

Comment: You just need to move the code in the tree class. But I was told that it does not work correctly, it needs to be recast

Comment: This code:public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return isEquals(obj);
    }

Comment: After edded private boolean isEquals(Object obj)............................. i don t know

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Given two trees, return true if they are
   structurally identical */
boolean identicalTrees(Node a, Node b) 
{
    /*1. both empty */
    if (a == null && b == null)
        return true;

    /* 2. both non-empty -> compare them */
    if (a != null && b != null) 
        return (a.data == b.data
                && identicalTrees(a.left, b.left)
                && identicalTrees(a.right, b.right));

    /* 3. one empty, one not -> false */
    return false;
}
```

then just use this method for the root nodes of your two trees.

Comment: I have another trees. And i don can write equals but i learn java recently.